# How to create and remove many Child Objects without bogging down the CPU or RAM in AS3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, actionscript, ram, movieclip

I am making a companion app for a Monopoly-esque game I'm designing. My goal is to have all the properties have a MovieClip that displays who owns it and how much it has been upgraded. There are literally hundreds of properties, and each one bogs down my run time by about a second (I set up a 1-sec timer to see how long it takes to run).

I have a MovieClip that will "spawn in" each property as I need. The idea being, I have a button that tells this MC to go to frame 10, and frame 10 will have code that adds the child for Property 10, and then that child contains all the necessary code. This child spawning MC looks like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();
// I used a "fakeChild" as a placeholder to get something spawned in so that there is something to be removed
var fake_Child: fakeChild = new fakeChild(); 

var property_Pale15: propertyPale15 = new propertyPale15();
var property_Red15: propertyRed15 = new propertyRed15();

removeChildAt(1);
addChildAt(fake_Child, 1);
```

And every subsequent frame for a given property looks like this (the property in this case is "Pale 15")

```
removeChildAt(1);
addChildAt(property_Pale15, 1);
property_Pale15.newData();
property_Pale15.propertyOwner();
```

I currently only have two test properties, and each one bogs down my timer by about a second, which is very bad. The properties themselves have an immense amount of code, which looks like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var myPropertyData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myLocalData");

var propertyName: String = ("Pale 15");
propertyDisplay.text = propertyName;

var propertyValue: int;

var propertyRent: int;
var activePlayer: int;
var currentRank: int;

loadData();

btnProperty.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateProperty);

function activateProperty(e:MouseEvent):void{

    propertyValue = MovieClip(root).valuePale15;    
    
    if(MovieClip(root).buyupgradeAction == true && loanedProperty.visible == false){
        buyupgradeProperty();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).paycostAction == true && bridgeProperty.visible == false && loanedProperty.visible == false){
        paycostProperty();
    }
}

function buyupgradeProperty(e:MouseEvent = null){
    
// Active Player (if Owner) Upgrades Property
    
    if(activePlayer == 1 && MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 1 && currentRank < 10){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 -= propertyValue * 0.8;
        currentRank += 1;
        currentRankDisplay.text = currentRank;
        propertyRent = propertyValue * currentRank * currentRank * 0.1;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " upgraded " + propertyName + " to Rank " + currentRank + " for $" + propertyValue * 0.8 + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(activePlayer == 2 && MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 2 && currentRank < 10){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 -= propertyValue * 0.8;
        currentRank += 1;
        currentRankDisplay.text = currentRank;
        propertyRent = propertyValue * currentRank * currentRank * 0.1;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " upgraded " + propertyName + " to Rank " + currentRank + " for $" + propertyValue * 0.8 + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(activePlayer == 3 && MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 3 && currentRank < 10){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 -= propertyValue * 0.8;
        currentRank += 1;
        currentRankDisplay.text = currentRank;
        propertyRent = propertyValue * currentRank * currentRank * 0.1;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " upgraded " + propertyName + " to Rank " + currentRank + " for $" + propertyValue * 0.8 + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(activePlayer == 4 && MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 4 && currentRank < 10){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 -= propertyValue * 0.8;
        currentRank += 1;
        currentRankDisplay.text = currentRank;
        propertyRent = propertyValue * currentRank * currentRank * 0.1;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " upgraded " + propertyName + " to Rank " + currentRank + " for $" + propertyValue * 0.8 + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }
    
// Active Player buys Property
    
    if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 1 && currentFrame == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 -= propertyValue;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.propertyDisplay1 += 1;
        gotoAndStop(2);
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0xFF0000);
        colorChange();
        propertyRent = 0;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " purchased " + propertyName + " for $" + propertyValue + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 2 && currentFrame == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 -= propertyValue;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.propertyDisplay2 += 1;
        gotoAndStop(3);
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0x0000FF);
        colorChange();
        propertyRent = 0;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " purchased " + propertyName + " for $" + propertyValue + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 3 && currentFrame == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 -= propertyValue;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.propertyDisplay3 += 1;
        gotoAndStop(4);
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0x00FF00);
        colorChange();
        propertyRent = 0;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " purchased " + propertyName + " for $" + propertyValue + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 4 && currentFrame == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 -= propertyValue;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.propertyDisplay4 += 1;
        gotoAndStop(5);
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0xFFFF00);
        colorChange();
        propertyRent = 0;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " purchased " + propertyName + " for $" + propertyValue + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }
    
    saveData();
}

function paycostProperty(e:MouseEvent = null){
    
    if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 1 && activePlayer == 2){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 1 && activePlayer == 3){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 1 && activePlayer == 4){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 2 && activePlayer == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 2 && activePlayer == 3){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 2 && activePlayer == 4){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 3 && activePlayer == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 3 && activePlayer == 2){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 3 && activePlayer == 4){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 4 && activePlayer == 1){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay1 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay1 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 4 && activePlayer == 2){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay2 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay2 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }else if(MovieClip(root).activePlayer == 4 && activePlayer == 3){
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay4 -= propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.moneyDisplay3 += propertyRent;
        MovieClip(root).transactionLog = (MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay4 + " paid " + MovieClip(root).myLocalData.data.nameDisplay3 + " $" + propertyRent + " for landing on " + propertyName + " (" + MovieClip(root).Time_txt.text + ")")
        MovieClip(root).updateLogs();
    }
    
    saveData();
}

function saveData(e:MouseEvent = null){
    myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rent = propertyRent;
    myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rank = currentRank;
    myPropertyData.data.Pale15Frame = currentFrame;
    myPropertyData.data.Pale15Loan = loanedProperty.visible;
    myPropertyData.data.Pale15Bridge = bridgeProperty.visible;
    
    myPropertyData.flush();
}

function loadData(e:Event = null){
    propertyRent = myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rent;
    currentRank = myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rank;
    gotoAndStop(myPropertyData.data.Pale15Frame);
    loanedProperty.visible = myPropertyData.data.Pale15Loan;
    bridgeProperty.visible = myPropertyData.data.Pale15Bridge;
}

function newData(e:Event = null){
    if(MovieClip(root).gameSave == 1){
        myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rent = 0;
        myPropertyData.data.Pale15Rank = 0;
        myPropertyData.data.Pale15Frame = 1;
        myPropertyData.data.Pale15Loan = false;
        myPropertyData.data.Pale15Bridge = false;
        loadData();
    }
}

function propertyOwner(e:Event = null){
    if(activePlayer == 1){
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0xFF0000);
        colorChange();
    }else if(activePlayer == 2){
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0x0000FF);
        colorChange();
    }else if(activePlayer == 3){
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0x00FF00);
        colorChange();
    }else if(activePlayer == 4){
        MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor.color = (0xFFFF00);
        colorChange();
    }
}

function colorChange (e:MouseEvent = null){
    MovieClip(root).stageProperties.Pale15.transform.colorTransform = MovieClip(root).stageProperties.propertyColor;
}
```

I tried to keep the code as general as possible so I could copy and paste for the other properties. Currently, this property is able to be purchased, upgraded, and dish out rent to the proper players based on what buttons are active, as well as tell a "Property Display" to change colors on the board based on who owns what.

Note: I have used AS3 for a very long time, but have no formal training, it is all self taught. I have tried many many times to understand how "parent/child/private class/etc" work, and I cannot grasp it. I wonder if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The script you provided, despite being quite... let's say, non-algorithmic, does not really look like it could run for a whole second. How do you measure that?

Comment: I know it is quite barbaric.. I just don't know how to make it efficient yet :) I made a makeshift timer buy making a simple 30-Frame long MC with a "0:00" on the first frame, "0:01" on the second frame, etc. And the application runs at 30fps, so in theory, the MC should take exactly 1 second to run. Timing it currently, it takes about 5.5 seconds, only getting longer if I add more properties...I've been doing some research and it looks like I may need to removeEventListeners? I'm not sure, but it seems even when not being spawned, all properties on the propertyButton timeline take up memory.

Comment: I also see you commented on my last question months ago, and I never thanked you! Still the same project, and still barely any idea what I'm doing ^-^

Comment: That's some serious copypaste code... I'm not even sure the error is somewhere here, you are probably running quite a set of `TextField`s that are repopulated each enterframe instead, or whatever else that you are trying to recreate per frame. This is a BAD MOVE anywhere, you only create and update objects when needed, especially heavy properties like drawn text.

Comment: @Vesper Could you elaborate on that? I apologize. So the bulk of this code ends up updating each player's money when affected, along with Property Rank when upgraded, and Property Rent when upgraded. Are you saying I should not be updating all these values? I know there is a way to do it with classes and packages, but anytime I use a class, I get "Cannot use a class outside of a package" and when I use a package, I get "Was not expecting a package". I think I have to link it externally somehow? But have no idea how to do that, and barely an idea on how classes work entirely.

Comment: Do you put the class script into a frame?

Comment: At this time, I have no class script whatsoever. (currently trying to drive it into my skull) On the main timeline, the Property Values are established (Pale 15 = 500) and the Booleans for whether or not someone can Buy Property or Upgrade Property are also there. Everything else is inside of the Property itself, which is an MC that gets spawned in by another MC (propertyButton) when it hits a certain frame of its own timeline.

Comment: Main Timeline ---> Moves propertyButton MC to a certain frame ---> each frame of propertyButton MC spawns a different Property MC (like Pale 15) and removes the previous Property MC ---> Property MC gets unique Property value (500) from Main Timeline and bases all its values from there...... Sorry I know this is an absolute mess ^-^

Comment: Could you, possibly, explain, what are you trying to achieve? Not the code, but, you know, user stories, use cases, some sort of GDD?

Comment: Like what I'm trying to achieve with the application? So this is basically a Companion App to a very large Monopoly-like game I'm creating, to be used while playing the game. My goal is to have 4 players, each with their Money and Property Owned count on display. There are various actions to perform in the form of buttons. In essence, I want to click a Player to make them active, then click an Action Button to perform an action (like "Buy Property" or "Pay Rent"), click on a directory of Buttons to find the right Property, and finally click on the Property I desire to execute the action. ^-^

Comment: Tip: the triple backtick device to format code needs to be on its own line. Optionally, you can put a format name there, e.g. `javascript` after the triple backtick, on the same line. Don't put your first line of code there - it will not render on the screen. I've fixed the post.

Comment: @Rofl247 I already mentioned it on the other question, now I'm pretty sure. You need to learn **OOP** principles and **AS3** classes as implementation of those principles. Just think of it: you need a single class to define the behavior for **ALL** the monopoly buildings, and it will be simple clean code once you learn the algorithmic approach and abstractions. Now your application obviously drowns under the weight of your code. How much code you will need if you want to add 4 more players? Like, x2 what you have now? That's **TOTALLY** wrong.

Comment: In order to use classes, you need a separate *.as file somewhere close to your FLA, and be able to link that class file to either a sprite or a MC. I am not familiar with Adobe's interface but remember they have the ability to do both. The class AS file can be edited with a normal text editor, as it's a file that only contains script. In that As file you can write `package { class XXX extends YYY { ... } }` and then refer to that XXX elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Okay, for the past few days I've been trying to learn classes and .as files and everything, and I've been coding all night. I think I'm getting close, trying to move my current timeline coding into .as files. Currently, I have the above Property code in a .as file, and I'm running into a few errors. For one thing, code within the .as cannot seem to access the main stage through MovieClip(root). arguments... Is this a common thing or is there a workaround? Also, my propertyButton cannot access the Property class to spawn in Pale 15 it seems. 
var property_Pale15: Property = new Property();

Comment: @Rofl247 You also should stop thinking in terms "*access root to ...*" It is an application. It needs some kind of architecture. Like, field manager that controls both players and buildings, while watching them for their events, players and buildings do not try to reach to the manager but dispatch events instead.

Comment: @Organis I think I get what you're saying. I'm just going slow while I learn this new and strange OOP thing. I've actually made good progress, I just have one major issue hanging me up (similar to my question from months ago). I have a Shape <addChild(Pale15)> and I want to access that shape, or any shape, with this function <stageProperties.Pale15.transform.colorTransform>. THIS WORKS, however I would like to replace the "Pale15" with a value from an index, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is as close as I've got: <stageProperties.(saveArray[propertySave]).transform.colorTransform>

Comment: Per the above, "propertySave" is an int I can change at will, and "saveArray" is the array with property names. Currently if I trace "saveArray[propertySave]", I yield the desired result, which is "Pale15". I just can't seem to fit it into the equation.

Comment: @Rofl247 This **stageProperties.Pale15.transform.colorTransform** is exactly not an **OOP** approach. **OOP** dictates that buildings (you call them properties) have certain behavior. You can pull some public methods, say **enter(who:Player)**, **exit(who:Player)**, **purchase(who:Player)**, **upgrade(who:Player)**, **hasOwner():Boolean** and **getOwner():Player**, so the building behaves with its current state in mind. Building also tends to its visuals, like color, itself, you don't need to access things from the outside.

Comment: @Organis Sorry, this function I'm trying to do has actually nothing to do with the "buildings" themselves. "stageProperties" is a separate entity, a grid pattern, with no functionality other than to highlight tiles on itself with the color of the person who owns them. Just a way of visually representing who owns what so everyone can see. And keep in mind, this will still be a physical board game, this app is meant to be used as a banking app only. So I still just need a way to target the shapes drawn on this grid with a dynamic variable, if that's possible. Thank you again for all your help!!

Comment: @Rofl247 That, again, is a non-OOP thinking. Instead, you should give a "building" behavior that, upon being purchased, records the player as its **owner** then uses the **color** property of the **owner** (yes, it's a nice idea to give each player a distinct **color** value so that player figure can be colored accordingly as well as the buildings this player owns) to color ITSELF properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me write some scripts in order to explain what **OOP**-thinking is about. Also, I **strongly** advise you to read and understand the idea of [MVC pattern](https://www.guru99.com/mvc-tutorial.html) because scripts below represent **[M]** and **[C]**, while **[V]** is not really important and adding it later on is not too difficult too as long as you have the architecture of your application straight.

First, let's define the gameboard cell, a place the players can pass by or visit.

```
package
{
    // A data [M]odel class.
    public class Place
    {
        // What do we call this place.
        public var title:String = "";
        
        // A guest list.
        public var visitors:Array = new Array;
        
        // The Person class will be defined later.
        
        public function visit(who:Person):void
        {
            // Add the guest to the list of visitors.
            visitors.push(who);
        }
        
        public function leave(who:Person):void
        {
            // Remove the visitor and remove its location record.
            var anIndex:int = visitors.indexOf(who);
            
            visitors.splice(anIndex, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Person** class so it would be able to visit and leave places.

```
package
{
    // A data [M]odel class.
    public class Person
    {
        // Personal name.
        public var title:String = "";
        
        // A place of residence.
        public var stayingAt:Place;
    }
}
```

To glue them together we need some controller that allows to move people from place to place. The idea is to **NEVER** address the **[M]** objects **Person** and **Place** directly, so the **[C]** script below ensures that a **Person** is always leaving and visiting properly, doesn't sit over 10 **Place**s, etc.

```
package
{
    // A [C]ontroller class.
    public class City
    {
        // City name.
        public var title:String = "";
        
        public function move(who:Person, where:Place):void
        {
            // Remove the guest from where it is currently staying.
            if (who.stayingAt)
            {
                who.stayingAt.leave(who);
                who.stayingAt = null;
            }
            
            where.visit(who);
            who.stayingAt = where;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in terms of Monopoly, what a **Building** is? It is a kind of **Place**, but with more complicated behavior. Then a **Player** is a **Person** who has money, can own buildings ant take turns to do things.

```
package
{
    // A data [M]odel class.
    public class Player extends Person
    {
        public var money:int;
        
        public var color:uint;
        
        public var turnsToAct:int;
        
        // A list of owned buildings.
        public var owns:Array = new Array;
        
        // Charges money from the Player
        // then returns how much was actually charged.
        public function charge(value:int):int
        {
            var acharge:int = 0;

            if (value <= 0)
            {
                // You cannot charge non-positive sums.
            }
            else if (money - value < 0)
            {
                // Bankruptcy handling block.
                acharge = Math.max(0, money);
                turnsToAct = 1000000;
                money -= value;
            }
            else
            {
                acharge = value;
                money -= value;
            }
            
            return acharge;
        }
    }
}
```

So, a **Building** be like...

```
package
{
    // A data [M]odel class.
    public class Building extends Place
    {
        public var owner:Player;
        public var color:uint;
        
        public var cost:int;
        public var rent:int;
        
        public function purchase(who:Player):void
        {
            who.charge(cost);
            
            owner = who;
            color = owner.color;
        }
        
        // Building can take rent from a visiting Player.
        // So, the "visit" method needs some additional behavior.
        override public function visit(who:Person):void
        {
            // Invoke previously defined visit logic.
            super.visit(who);
            
            // If the Building is not owned, there's no rent.
            // There's also no rent, if the owner visits.
            if (!owner || who == owner) return;
            
            // Person class does not have "charge" method. Read up "typecasting".
            
            // The following one line is actually that HORRIBLE block
            // of code named "paycostProperty" in your question.
            owner.money += (who as Player).charge(rent);
            // Seriously.
        }
    }
}
```

So, there are some things left to do (I am getting lazy and not going to program here the whole Monopoly thing):

- Devise **City.init()** method so that it creates an ordered list of **Player**s, an ordered list of **Place**s and **Building**s and moves all the **Player**s to the first cell.
- Compose the logic to control turns and the flow of the **Player** taking its turn: cast a die, move, make decisions, complete its turn.
- Design the **[V]** components to display **Player**s' stats, **Place**s and **Building**s with all their possible states, the **City** to visualise the overall state of things.

Comment: I'd say, this is well more than I could have asked for!! Thank you so much, and thank you to everyone else who tried to help me fix my tangled web of nonsense!! ^-^

Comment: @Rofl247 Well, I hope that will help you to start **thinking** the right way, because design-driven approach "*so I designed it as it should look now let's write some codes*" is a dead end as soon as you have more than 5-10 frames of scripts.